# List of Tables and Figures change the spacing between the dots, dotfill

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, leaders

Using a List of Tables and Figures, see link below.

How can I change the spacing between the dots? Is it called "leaders" or "dotfill"?

I can adjust the spacing in the ToC using `\renewcommand\cftsecleader{\cftdotfill{1.5}}`

Here the code chunk for LoF with a header: Figures & Page

```
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}p{.45\textwidth}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
    \raggedright
    Figures & Page
\end{tabular*}
\listoffigures
```

How to adjust the spacing of dots for `\listoffigures`?

[Link to List of Tables and Figures tutorial](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Lists_of_tables_and_figures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `\cftdotsep` to a different number (default is `4.5`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{8}% Default is 4.5

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A figure.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, works great!

Answer (score 0):

With the `tocloft` package by default the separation between **all** the dots is set by the value of `\cftdotsep` whose initial specification is `\newcommand{\cftdotsep}{4.5}`. If you change this to another number, say 10, then the spacing between the dots will increase. You can set different spacings for different entries by changing the `\cftXdotsep` macro, where `X` can be `part` or `chap` or `sec` or `subsec` ... or `fig` or `tab` or ... for the several kinds of entries from `\part` downwards. See **Section 2.3** in the
manual (`> texdoc tocloft`).

```
% tocprob22.tex  SE 517031  changing dotsep

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{10} % increase default spacing
\renewcommand*{\cftsubsecdotsep}{20} % very wide spacing for subsections
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand*{\cftfigdotsep}{15} % medium spacing for figures
\listoffigures
% tables use the \cftdotsep spacing
\listoftables

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\centering
FIGURE
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{A table}
TABLE
\end{table}

\subsection{A subsection}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

However, it is best to have all dots separated by the same amount, so normalyy just changing `\cftdotsep` is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you, I understand this better now, WORKS! I have one segment with a manual dotfill ```\newcommand\myleaders{\cftdotfill{1.5}} 
\def\mypara#1#2{\noindent#1\myleaders\makebox[1.7em][r]{#2}}``` Can this be modified so that if follows ```\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{10}``` ?

Comment: @togedo I have no idea. Please ask a new question showing what you have done and what you want,